# Postgresql jsonb support in orm lite servicestack

Tags: postgresql, ormlite-servicestack

Can we expect native support for the jsonb field when saving poco objects into a field? (and query for fields inside the jsonb field using the correct postgresql syntax)?

Thanks

Comment: Oeps, jsonb instead of bson. It's already supported with native t-sql support in nested fields. Using linq inside orm-lite that is converted into the correct postgresql syntax for jsonb fields would be very handy!